# I've got error message OverQuotaError, However I have quota enough

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

When I send email in the GAE(python), I got error message `OverQuotaError`.

But my quota doesn't overflow.

Below is my Appengine Email quota. I just consume 1% quota.

```
Mail API Calls  0%   0%  202 of 1,771,789    Okay
Recipients Emailed  1%   1%  202 of 20,100   Okay
Admins Emailed  0%   0%  0 of 3,492,979  Okay
Message Body Data Sent  0%   0%  0.00 of 29.58 GBytes    Okay
Attachments Sent    0%   0%  0.00 of 0.00 GBytes     Okay
Attachment Data Sent    0%   0%  0.00 of 106.96 GBytes   Okay
```

And my app print error like this.

```
OverQuotaError: The API call mail.Send() required more quota than is available.
```

I know send bulk mail is stop by google. So I added `Time.sleep(2)`.

Thank you.

Comment: There are other quota's to look at, for instance you could be over quota on cpu hours.  On a seperate topic this question is not a good fit for SO this question it is not really programming related in terms of the way the question is written.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GAE for free, then I think you should change `time.sleep(2)` to `time.sleep(8)`, since GAE allows only 8 messages to be sent per minute (see details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail)). You may also need to check the size of your messages and its attachments.